# Auto Refresh div with DataFrame every N seconds

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I have seen a lot of solutions for this around the net but can't find the easiest solution for this .... simple flask page that loads a df into the html table. All I want to do is reload just the df in the html table every N seconds and not the whole page.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from app import app
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
cn = sa.create_engine('<my connection string>')

@app.route("/")
def home():
    sql = "select * from <myTable>"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql,cn)
    return render_template("index.html", df=df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr style="background-color:#a8a8a8">
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for index, row in df.iterrows(): %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row["Column_1"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row["Column_2"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ row["Column_3"] }}</td>
            <tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help on my next steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately flask doesn't support live-reload (in core at least). You should javascript to get new data every n seconds or reload all of page completely.

Comment: You'll probably want to end up using a frontend framework like Vue or React.

Comment: "I have seen a lot of solutions for this around the net but can't find the easiest solution for this ". What have you seen? What have you tried? What exactly do you mean by easiest solution?
As @Buğraİşgüzar mentioned, generally this is done via ajax, and javascript

Comment: I have seen a javascript that looks like this but I do not know how to implement it into the Flask app:
setInterval(function(){
      $('#test').load('test.html');
 },5000);

Comment: If reloading all of page is not a problem for you, you can use meta tags to reload page for every N seconds. It's look like the easiest way in your case. Details: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: @dasrocko The example you posted there does look right, but it is using jquery. Which is great and all, but if you are struggling with this I would start looking google searches along this line "ajax using vanilla javascript"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you,
However I highly recommend testing this out and updating your page partially with a test string before working with the data frame. The ajax method and the flask routes are correct. But I am not 100% sure about the conversion of dataframes to json, you will have to look into that

The output of this will print out the "random_dictionary" to your browser console every 2000 milliseconds

## index.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border=1>
        <!-- Your existing code -->
    </table>
</div>
<script>

//The setInterval() method repeats a given function at every given time-interval.
//Syntax: setInterval(function, milliseconds)

//Calls the update_data_frame function every 2000 milliseconds
var myVar = setInterval(update_data_frame, 2000);

//This function makes a POST request to the flask route "/update"
//The value of return response.json() is the return value of the "/update"
//In your case this is going to be the dataframe
//".then(function(myjson))..." captures the return value to be used as required
function update_data_frame () {
    url = '/update';
    fetch(url,{method:'POST'})
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson)
    {
      store = myJson;
      //This line prints out "{somedata":"somedatavalue","somedata1":"somedatavalue1"}" every 2000 milliseconds
      console.log(store);
    });
  }

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------

## app.py

```
@app.route('/update',methods=['POST'])
def update_data_frame():
    #this should be your dataframe
    random_dictionary = {"somedata":"somedatavalue","somedata1":"somedatavalue1"}
    return jsonify(random_dictionary )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

app.py

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/df")
def df4reload():
    sql = "select * from <myTable>"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql,cn)
    return render_template("df.html", df=df)
```

index.html

```
{%extends "base.html"%}

{% block content %}
    <div id="df"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $('#df').load('/df'); //Preloads df
        var timeout = setInterval(reloadDF, 5000);    
        function reloadDF () {
            $('#df').load('/df');
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

df.html

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border=1>
    <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:#a8a8a8">
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for index, row in df.iterrows(): %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row["Column_1"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row["Column_2"] }}</td>
            <td>{{ row["Column_3"] }}</td>
        <tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works for me.  If anyone has any better or different solutions, please let me know.