# Clear Flask Form after submit without refreshing page

Tags: html, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm building a simple To-Do List app in Flask, and I've created a form that's supposed to add a task within a user's account.

Flask Form:

```
class AddTask(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators = [DataRequired()])
    description = StringField('Description')
    project = SelectField('Project', choices = [], validators = [DataRequired()])
    due_date_time = DateField('Due Date', format = '%Y-%m-%d')
    priority = RadioField('Priority', choices = [(1, 'Priority 1'), (2, 'Priority 2'), (3, 'Priority 3'), (4, 'Priority 4')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Task')
    attributes_to_clear = [title, description, project, due_date_time, priority]
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class = "new_task_form">
        <form action = "/app/today" method = "POST">
            {{ new_task_form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ new_task_form.csrf_token }}
            {{ new_task_form.title.label }}
            {{ new_task_form.title }}
            {% if new_task_form.title.errors %}
                <ul class="errors">
                    {% for error in new_task_form.errors %}
                        <li>{{ error }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
            {{ new_task_form.description.label }}
            {{ new_task_form.description }}
            {{ new_task_form.project.label }}
            {{ new_task_form.project }}
            {{ new_task_form.due_date_time.label }}
            {{ new_task_form.due_date_time }}
            {{ new_task_form.priority.label }}
            {{ new_task_form.priority }}
            {{ new_task_form.submit() }}
        </form>
    </div>
```

Route:

```
@app.route('/app/today', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def today():
    today = datetime.today().strftime('%a %b %d')
    projects = [(project.id, project.title) for project in Project.query.filter(Project.user_id == current_user.id).all()]
    new_task_form = AddTask()
    new_task_form.project.choices = projects
    logger.info(f'new_task_form.project.choices: {new_task_form.project.choices}')
    if new_task_form.validate_on_submit():
        logger.info(f'new_task_form.validate_on_submit() returned {new_task_form.validate_on_submit()}')
        project_from_form = Project.query.filter(Project.id == new_task_form.project.data).first()
        logger.error(f'project_from_form: {project_from_form}')
        new_task = Task(
            title = new_task_form.title.data,
            description = new_task_form.description.data,
            project = project_from_form,
            due_date_time = new_task_form.due_date_time.data,
            priority_level = new_task_form.priority.data,
            user_id = current_user.id
        )
        db.session.add(new_task)
        db.session.commit()
    else:
        logger.info(f'new_task_form.validate_on_submit(): Returned {new_task_form.validate_on_submit()}')
        logger.info(f'new_task_form.errors: {new_task_form.errors}')
    pending_tasks = Task.query.filter(Task.user_id == current_user.id, Task.completed_status == 0).all()
    pending_tasks_length = len(pending_tasks)
    logger.info(f'current_user: {current_user.id}')
    logger.info(f'pending_tasks_length: {pending_tasks_length}')
    logger.info(f'pending_tasks: {pending_tasks}')
    return render_template('today.html',
        day_and_date = today,
        new_task_form = new_task_form,
        user_projects = projects,
        pending_tasks_length = pending_tasks_length,
        pending_tasks = pending_tasks)
```

The issue I'm running into is that I don't want the page to refresh after submitting. Right now it works in the sense that you can add a task and it'll populate immediately on the page. However, the actual Flask Form will keep whatever you plugged in previously and a refresh will cause it to resubmit. I've looked around but couldn't find a way to eliminate the text, I've tired using the `default` values, building functions that would reset them to just an empty string, but nothing I've tried so far fixes this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@app.route('/app/today', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def today():
    #do some stuff
    if new_task_form.validate_on_submit():
        #do stuff and add to database
        db.session.add(new_task)
        db.session.commit()
        return  redirect(url_for('today'))
    else:
        #do stuff if the form is not validated properly
        return  redirect(url_for('today'))
    #contuinou
  
    return render_template('today.html', #pass some stuff to the page)
```

The idea is that after form validation if you redirect to the current page, the flask actually clears your form data and it won't be submitted again when the user refreshes the page. After redirecting, the form will be completely empty.

Comment: Thanks, will look into this as a potential solution! I'm still new to Flask and Python and so forth, so this really helps!

Comment: This worked out perfectly, although now I'm curious about Gage Hilyard's answer as to how to use JS to go about this. But thanks for the pointers!

Comment: hmmm. contuinou

Answer (score 0):

Here you are sending this html to the user even after submitting a successful entry to your database with the same form that has been completed

```
return render_template('today.html',
        day_and_date = today,
        new_task_form = new_task_form,
        user_projects = projects,
        pending_tasks_length = pending_tasks_length,
        pending_tasks = pending_tasks)
```

What you are trying to do will require some javascript since flask cannot do this on its own.
I suggest reading this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62081993/22796342
They provide this code:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();    // prevent page from refreshing
        const formData = new FormData(form);  // grab the data inside the form fields
        fetch('/', {   // assuming the backend is hosted on the same server
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        }).then(function(response) {
            // do something with the response if needed.
            // If you want the table to be built only after the backend handles the request and replies, call buildTable() here.
        });
    });
```

Comment: Got it, I know a little JavaScript but just basics, I'll look into this and see how I can implement this. I needed to get more familiar with JS anyway!